# Custom Wagtail permissions

Tags: django, wagtail

Hello my fellow developers. I need help with permissions for Wagtail site. So my situation is this, I need to create pages that required the user to be logged in. The problem is that django  permissions revolve around views. Wagtail does not views but classes (Page Model).

So these private pages will be under '/portal/'.
I don't know how many pages there will be. I am hoping to continue wagtails for creating dynamic pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the edit page in the admin interface, click Privacy (Public) in the top right corner, then select "Private, accessible to logged-in users". Further documentation here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/advanced_topics/privacy.html

Comment: Would it better to control permissions from the backend so that new developers wouldn't need to know wagtail to continue maintaining the site?

Comment: I wouldn't say so - setting up protected sections is a task for the site administrator, not for a programmer, so it makes sense for it to be done through the admin rather than in code. See https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/getting_started/the_zen_of_wagtail.html#always-wear-the-right-hat